# Check if there is an object assigned to function in R

Tags: r

I have quite a simple problem that I am stuck on.

Lets say I have a function `foo`. I want it to behave differently depending on whether there is an object assigned to it i.e. `foo()` will print `"Please assign an object to foo!"` and `data<-foo()` will just assign a dataframe to the object `data`.

Is there a function that can check this so I can incorporate a logical test in `foo`? `match.call` doesn't tell if the output is being assigned to an object unfortunately.

Comment: No I don't think this is possible. The reason is that *first* the RHS (your function `foo`) will get evaluated, and *then* its output will be assigned to the LHS side (either your object `data`, or to the STDOUT connection).

Comment: This does sound a bit like a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). If you provide a bit more context to the problem you're facing, it might be easier for us to help.

Comment: Seems like you want the opposite of `invisible()` (which I don't think exists).

Comment: Okay so lets take mtcars for example, and say I have the historical prices of all the cars in the mtcars dataframe. So `foo(hp=110)` will return the mtcars dataframe with only cars with column hp =110. Essentially `foo(hp=110)` prints `mtcars[which(mtcars$hp==110),]`. But `data<-foo(hp=110)` will assign the historical prices xts of the three cars with hp=100, into the object `data`, with the data downloaded from a database elsewhere.  So `data` will contain an xts of 3 columns, 1 column per historical price of car.

Comment: I know there are other ways to do this without complicating it for myself but it seems like the most "user friendly" way to do it. The above is already done, I just need to find a way to `print` when its `foo(hp=110)`

Comment: Your comment is different than your question - you want something that *prints* in a specific way that is different from it's structure. You just need to make your own S3 class and define a `print` method for it that prints what you want. If the object is assigned, that will work still work normally.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is not really in the spirit of how R works.

If you must do it anyways then a workaround would be instead of using the form:

```
output <- foo(input)
```

pass the name of the output to `foo` as an argument.  Then we can do this:

```
foo <- function(name, input, envir = parent.frame()) {
  stopifnot(is.character(name))
  output <- input    # can replace this with complex transformation
  assign(name, output, envir)
}

# test it checking that abc was assigned to
foo("abc", 3)
abc
## [1] 3
```